# React.js inline function getting error onClick: TypeError: _this2.<function-name> is not a function

Tags: reactjs

I'm stuck on this simple issue where when I click on a button, I'm trying to fire multiple functions at the same time, inside of an `onClick` event on a button. However, when I try to do this, I get this error:

`Uncaught TypeError: _this2.removeLocation is not a function`

Here is my function:

```
const renderLocations = ({ fields, meta: { touched, error, submitFailed } }) => {

    return (
      <div>
        <div className={styles.contactInfoSection}>
          <h2>Locations</h2>
          <div>
            <button type="button" className={styles.add} onClick={() => fields.push({})}>Add Location</button>
            {(touched || submitFailed) && error && <span>{error}</span>}
          </div>
        </div>
        <ul className={styles.locationsList}>
          {fields.map((location, index) =>
            <li className={styles.locationCard} key={index}>
              <div>
                <Field
                  name={`${location}.street`}
                  hintText="Street"
                  component={TextField}
                  label="Street"/>
                <Field
                  name={`${location}.city`}
                  hintText="City"
                  component={TextField}
                  label="City"/>
                <Field
                  name={`${location}.state`}
                  hintText="State"
                  component={TextField}
                  label="State"/>
                <Field
                  name={`${location}.zip`}
                  hintText="Zip"
                  component={TextField}
                  label="Zip"/>
              </div>
              <button
                type="button"
                title="Remove"
                onClick={() => {
                  fields.remove(index);
                  this.removeLocation();
                }}>Remove</button>
            </li>
          )}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

I'm trying to fire a function from inside my component that looks like this:

```
export class ManageCustomerForm extends React.Component { 

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    //this.removeLocation = this.removeLocation.bind(this);
  }

  removeLocation() {
    console.log('remove location?');
    this.props.removeLocation();
  }

}
```

Does anyone know what the issue here is?

Comment: Are these part of the same component? If not, `this.removeLocation` will have to be passed down to `renderLocations` as a property. Currently `renderLocations` has no visibility of `this.removeLocation` as `this` points to the `renderLocations` function.

Comment: I don't think you've included `removeLocation` in `renderLocations`, which is why is throwing that error because it is probably undefined. Could you confirm that my statement is accurate?

Comment: where is your `this.removeLocation` ???!!!

Comment: hey D-reaper, yes you're correct. my `renderLocations` function does not contain removeLocation. Is there a way I can access this.props from inside the `renderLocations` function as well?

Comment: dpaulus, how would I go about passing as a property? They aren't technically part of the same component, but they are within the same file

Answer (score 0):

So what I did was converted my inline function into a a defined function inside of my component so I could access it inside of the same component.